# Questions about reversing object oriented code(initializing vtables in ctors)

Tags: c++

I was reversing some C++ code and encountered following function.

```
sub_106C0A0 proc near

var_10= dword ptr -10h
var_C= dword ptr -0Ch
var_4= dword ptr -4

push    0FFFFFFFFh
push    offset SEH_106C0A0
mov     eax, large fs:0
push    eax
mov     large fs:0, esp
push    ecx
push    esi
mov     esi, ecx
push    edi
lea     edi, [esi+4]
push    30h
mov     ecx, edi
mov     [esp+1Ch+var_10], esi
mov     dword ptr [esi], offset off_12C0680
call    struc_13_ctor
mov     dword ptr [edi], offset off_12C057C ; another vtable init ?
```

This function passes this pointer of some object (struc_13), which is esi+4, to the struc_13_ctor. Inside the struc_13_ctor function, it initializes the vtable pointer and other member variables.

```
; int __thiscall struc_13_ctor(struc_13 *this, __int16 a2)
struc_13_ctor proc near

arg_0= word ptr  4

mov     dx, [esp+arg_0]
mov     eax, ecx
xor     ecx, ecx
mov     dword ptr [eax], offset struc_13_vtable
mov     [eax+4], ecx
mov     [eax+8], ecx
mov     [eax+0Ch], dx
mov     [eax+0Eh], cx
mov     [eax+14h], ecx
mov     [eax+10h], ecx
retn    4
struc_13_ctor endp
```

However after returning from struc_13_ctor, it overwrites the vtable pointer with the new value, which is off_12C057C in this case.

```
call    struc_13_ctor
mov     dword ptr [edi], offset off_12C057C ; another vtable init ?
```

I have seen this kind of behaviors a lot while looking at ctor functions, but never understood why this happens.

Comment: Seems like assembly code, that you've pasted, does everything ok. What is exactly overwritten(edi?), when return value is in eax? If I remember correctly, return value may use in any future instruction and, as soon as you pasted only one instruction after function return, I can not say exactly what is happening then.

Comment: my question is that although ctor func initializes the vtable ptr of the struc_13, after returning vtable ptr of the struc_13 is re-initialized to a different value. edi points to the vtable ptr inside the struc_13 in the caller func

Comment: @seeya: The value of `edi` in the main function gets moved to `ecx`, then moved to `eax` in the `struc_13_ctor` function. So the `mov dword ptr [eax], offset struc_13_vtable` in the called function and the `mov dword ptr [edi], offset off_12C057C` access the same memory address. The OP's question was, why does the outer function overwrite the vtable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the c++ code would look something like this:

```
// has vtbl struc_13_vtable
// has constructor struc_13_ctor
struct struc_13 {
    int  a,b;
    short c,d;
    int e,f;

    struc_13(short x)
       : a(0), b(0), c(x), d(0), e(0), f(0)
    { }

    virtual void someotherfn();
};

// has vtbl off_12C057C
// has inlined constructor
struct derivedmember : struc_13 {
    derivedmember() : struc_13(0x30)
    { }
    virtual void someotherfn();
};

// has vtbl off_12C0680
// has constructor sub_106C0A0
struct A {
    derivedmember  member;
    virtual void somefn();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The class of which `sub_106C0A0` is a member function contains another class as a member. Assuming ecx is the class pointer, then it's ecx+4, not ecx, that gets passed to the inner constructor. So the inner class pointer is behind the vtable pointer of the outer class, which suggests something like:

```
class a {
    int i1, i2;
    short s1, s2;
    int i3, i4;

    a::a(int x) {
        i1=0; i2=0;
        s1=x;
        s2=0; i3=0; i4=0;
    } 
}

class b : public a {
    // whatever;
}

class outer {
    class b someelement;
    // more variables;

    outer::outer() {
        someelement=(b) new a(48);
    }
}
```

I'd assume the `sub_106C0A0` function allocates a class instance, then casts that to another class. The cast to the other class makes the compiler replace `a`'s vtable with `b`'s vtable. However, i'm not 100% sure how that makes sense - if `b` is a real superclass of `a`, then casting `a` to `b` isn't safe, because the additional members aren't there; if `b` is a subclass of `a`, then there's no reason to replace the vtable when casting.

Looking at the size and entries of the vtables might help - maybe the programmer used some weird method of abstract classes and implementation classes, where the class members of one class are the abstract classes (`b`), but what gets instantiated by `new()` are the implementations (`a`). (That still wouldn't be a good reason to replace the implementation vtable with the abstract class vtable, however).

Comment: sub_106C0A0 does not allocate, it constructs.